# Producer-Consumer-Problem using SQL Server and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Classic producer-consumer-problem.

I have x app servers which write records in a DB table (same DB).

On each server, a service is running which polls the DB table and is supposed to read the oldest entry, process it and delete it.
The issue is now that the services get into a race condition: service on server A starts reading, server B starts reading the same record. I'm a bit stuck on this...I have implemented producer-consumer so often but never across server barriers.

The server cannot talk to each other except over the DB.

Environment is SQL Server 2005 and ASP-NET 3.5.

Comment: How about adding a Processing flag to the table to effectively lock the row for processing whilst a specific server is processing the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pick up work in a transactional way, only one server can pick it up:

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read

update  top 1 tbl
set     ProcessingOnServer = HOST_NAME()
from    YourWorkTable tbl
where   ProcessingOnServer is null
        and Done = 0
```

Now you can select the details, knowing the work item is safely assigned to you:

```
select  *
from    YourWorkTable tbl
where   ProcessingOnServer = HOST_NAME()
        and Done = 0
```

The function `host_name()` returns the client name, but if you think it's safer you can pass in the hostname from your client application.

We usually add a timestamp, so you can check for servers that took too long to process an item.

Comment: But wouldn't it then be enough to just "set transaction isolation level repeatable read" without updating first and read directly?

Comment: @Krumelur: Hmm no, because then other processes could read at the same time.  A transaction is started with `begin transaction`, but it still will not acquire a lock before you actually read or write to a table.

Comment: I don't get it. In your example I don't see "begin transaction"...?

Comment: @Krumelur: A single statement (like the update here) is always transactional.  You'd need `begin transaction` if you queried the work row using `select`, to `update` it with a separate statement

Comment: This idea is amazing, saved my ass big time! :)

Comment: Can it be that easy! :-) If that works it a great example of thinking outside the box (update it before you read it, instead of reading locking messing and updating ...)